# What's an efficient way to convert "unsigned char" array to its "unsigned short" counterpart?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, short

What's an efficient way to convert "unsigned char" array to its "unsigned short" counterpart? I usually use the following code snippet to do so.

```
#define CH_LINE_PIXELS       2291
#define SCANLINE_SIZE        57301
#define CH1_INDEX            2297
#define CH2_INDEX            4592
#define CH3_INDEX            6887
#define CH4_INDEX            9182

unsigned char* pUChar = new unsigned char[SCANLINE_SIZE];

unsigned short *pUS1, *pUS2, *pUS3, *pUS4;
pUS1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(&pUChar[CH1_INDEX]);
pUS2 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(&pUChar[CH2_INDEX]);
pUS3 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(&pUChar[CH3_INDEX]);
pUS4 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(&pUChar[CH4_INDEX]);

unsigned short us1, us2;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < CH_LINE_PIXELS; i++) 
{   
    us1 = pUChar[CH1_INDEX + 2 * i];
    us2 = pUChar[CH1_INDEX + 2 * x + 1];
    pUS1[x] = us1 * 0x100 + us2;

    us1 = pUChar[CH2_INDEX + 2 * i];
    us2 = pUChar[CH2_INDEX + 2 * i + 1];
    pUS2[x] = us1 * 0x100 + us2;

    us1 = pUChar[CH3_INDEX + 2 * i];
    us2 = pUChar[CH3_INDEX + 2 * i + 1];
    pUS3[x] = us1 * 0x100 + us2;

    us1 = pUChar[CH4_INDEX + 2 * i];
    us2 = pUChar[CH4_INDEX + 2 * i + 1];
    pUS4[x] = us1 * 0x100 + us2;
}
```

Comment: I see that you forgot to read the giant sidebar entitled "How to format". Notice that it doesn't say anything about using HTML tags...

Comment: Specifically, it says to *just select all your code and press the  `{}` button. Please do that in the future.

Comment: Note that using `reinterpret_cast`  in this manner is **implementation dependent**: that is you cannot expect your code to behave the same way when compiled on a different compiler/platform.

Comment: Dear jalf Thank you for your kind remind on code format, I'll do in the future.

Comment: Dear ereOn, What's your suggestion on the removal of the compiler/platfor dependent "cast" operation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Addressing `short` on byte boundary may (or may not) cause alignment issues, depending on platform.

Also, multiplying is very ineffective, why not use shifting instead? (some compilers may optimize  `x * 0x100`, but if they don't - it's a huge performance hit when all you want is just `x << 8`...)

Also, as noted, `reinterpret_cast` may not work as you expect it to.

I would suggest, since you do assignments anyway, to copy values from array of `char` to a separate array of `short`. It costs some memory, but will save you oh so much trouble with unexpected crashes and what else.

Comment: Dear littleadv,
Thank you for your answer. To avoid boundary alignment problem, is it better and safer to use vector<unsigned char> and vector<unsigned short> to replace unsigned char*, and unsigned short* array?

Comment: "if they don't" - then they probably won't produce efficient code generally, so if you care about performance you need to turn on optimization, or get a better compiler.

Comment: why the downvote? Did I write something wrong? @Steve - re your comment: I'm just stating a fact. Sometimes the programmer may not be in a position to be able to change a compiler.

Comment: I don't think that "multiplying is very ineffective" or "some compilers may optimize" are very accurate descriptions of the situation, so I don't think those are facts. It's possible that some day you'll find yourself manually optimizing a multiplication to a shift in C++ code, and seeing a significant improvement, but it isn't the norm. I also don't think it's worth a downvote -- to me, a shift expresses this bit-twiddling operation as well as, or better than, multiplication. So I'd use it, just not for the reason you give.

Comment: @Steve - when you do shift - use shift. Multiplication overhead aside (which I disagree with you, respectively, on the dismissal of), it's a mere thing of code readability and reducing possibility of bugs (imaging writing `x * 100` instead of `x * 0x100`, go find it later on).

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should do:

`us1 << 8 + us2` instead of multiplying by 0x100, because you want to move the first 8 bits in the upper positions, and shifting is faster then multiplication.

E.g. you have `us1 = aaaaaaaa` (8bits) and `us2 = bbbbbbbb` (another 8bits). Extending these chars to shorts would be simply padding them with 8 zeroes on the left.

Then the formula above would give you:

```
00000000aaaaaaaa
<< 8
aaaaaaaa00000000
+ 00000000bbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb
```

On the other hand you should **allocate a new array of shorts** for your results.

Comment: "shifting is faster then multiplication" - if your compiler is rubbish.

Comment: Dear Steve, in this case, I'll take your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Dear Matyas, Thank you for your answer. Using shifting instead of multiplication, and don't let short pointer directly point to char array by decalring a separate short array instead. Your suggestion was almost the same as that of littleadv. Great minds think alike! I'll take your advice.  Thank you all.